# IntelliJ IDEA When debug show jars dependence file not found?

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

guys, I'm developing a java-fx project in IDEA. At first, the debug-model goes well, but somehow((；′⌒`) that means I don't remember where I had made a wrong operation?) it's broken. And then, when I go debug model again, it's says:

```
File Not Found Exception: file:/home/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bytedeco/javacv/1.5/f4a4cba80cb84fbe46f06a6f67df49aee6bdcc67/javacpp-1.5.jar
```

Which's throw by the function:

```
private JarFile getJarFile(URL var1) throws IOException {
    if (this.isOptimizable(var1)) {
        FileURLMapper var4 = new FileURLMapper(var1);
            if (!var4.exists()) {
                throw new FileNotFoundException(var4.getPath());
            } else {
                return checkJar(new JarFile(var4.getPath()));
            }
        } else {
            URLConnection var2 = this.getBaseURL().openConnection();
            var2.setRequestProperty("UA-Java-Version", URLClassPath.JAVA_VERSION);
            JarFile var3 = ((JarURLConnection)var2).getJarFile();

            return checkJar(var3);
        }
    }
}
```

It's weird, because I had implemented the ***javacpp-1.5*** dependence in build.gradle, here's the all the config-content:

```
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.5'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacpp', version: '1.5'

    implementation group: 'net.sf.proguard', name: 'proguard-base', version: '6.0.3'

    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'opencv', version: '4.0.1-1.5', classifier: 'linux-x86_64'
    implementation group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'ffmpeg', version: '4.1.3-1.5', classifier: 'linux-x86_64'

    implementation group: 'org.ejml', name: 'ejml-all', version: '0.39'
}
```

So, I had check the cache-directory, and only found ***javacv-1.5.jar***. However I had found the **javacpp-1.5.jar** in another directory:

```
/home/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bytedeco/javacpp/1.5/d655e7adf50f000307f982b4238e29dcce54ebc8/javacpp-1.5.jar
```

Great! Copy it! And debug again, show another same-type-exception again:

```
File Not Found Exception: file:/home/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bytedeco/javacv/1.5/f4a4cba80cb84fbe46f06a6f67df49aee6bdcc67/opencv-4.0.1-1.5.jar
```

But I had found the same jar in another directory under the same root of **org.bytedeco**:

```
/home/xxx/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.bytedeco/opencv/4.0.1-1.5/ed1488f93c062d028740a91867747806ae56ad42/opencv-4.0.1-1.5.jar
```

WHAT'S HAPPENED???

Copy it! The next exception is **ffmpeg-4.1.3-1.5.jar**! Found it in "org.bytedeco/ffmpeg/4.1.3-1.5/xxx/ffmpeg-4.1.3-1.5.jar"!

Copy it! The next exception is **flycapture-2.13.3.31-1.5.jar**!

ENDLESS!!!

I found all the compile dependencies of javacv-1.5 [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco/javacv-platform/1.5). It's seems my project lost all of them "**UNDER THE CACHES PATH OF 'JAVACV/1.5'**". And I had clean the caches by "File/Invalidate Caches", the problem never solved.

Need your help!

Comment: For convenience, please try to use javacv-platform with the Platform Plugin from Gradle JavaCPP: https://github.com/bytedeco/gradle-javacpp#the-platform-plugin

Answer (score 0):

1. `mvn clean`
2. close IDEA
3. delete all .idea and *.iml files in your project dir and sub module dir
4. restart IDEA
   This helped me to solve the problem.

Comment: Maybe say where the .idea and .iml files might be. Also, how it fixes the issue and if there are any some side effects of deleting them.